# Creating folders and subfolders on a network drive

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create folders and subfolders by getting full path from a worksheet. The path is of the type

\\astdfs.ast.lmco.com\data\S&NS\S&IS\F&BO\Estimating\Proposals\2018\1800098_GPS 1

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am getting bad file or number when trying to create the folder.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateFolders()

Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
Dim fullpath

With Sheet3
    lRow = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 9 To lRow
        fullpath = Trim(.Range("Y" & i).Value)
        If Len(fullpath) > 3 Then CreateDir (fullpath) 
    Next i

End With

End Sub


Sub CreateDir(strPath As String)
    Dim elm As Variant
    Dim strCheckPath As String

    strCheckPath = ""
    For Each elm In Split(strPath, "\")

        strCheckPath = strCheckPath & elm & "\"
        Debug.Print elm, strCheckPath

        If Len(elm) > 0 And elm <> "\" And elm <> "\\" Then
            If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath
        End If
    Next elm

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath` this line

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: bad filename or number

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since your path(s) may contain spaces, you'll need to end the path with a `\`. I'd also trim the string and check to see if the backslash is already the last character before you add it.

#### example

```
Public Sub test()
Dim strCheckPath As String

    strCheckPath = "C:\Temp\test space"
    If Right(Trim(strCheckPath), 1) <> "\" Then strCheckPath = Trim(strCheckPath) & "\"
    If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath
    
End Sub
```